# How to get the row with the actual index while iterator skips rows that are null

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using apache poi to parse a set of excel files. They all look like this.

[image]

My code is supposed to find the ID row and then locate the two rows before it in order to extract the content of the first cell of that row.

The code is as follows:

```
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            int rowIndex = 0;
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                row = rowIterator.next();
                rowIndex ++;
                cell = row.getCell(0);
                if (cell != null) {
                    if (rowIndex > 2) {
                      Row protocolRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex - 3);
                      String cellStr = protocolRow.getCell(0).getStringValue();
                    }
                }
            }
```

While the relative position of the two rows is fixed, index in method getRow(index) is the absolute row index of the spreadsheet. There are a lot of empty rows in the spreadsheet. Some of them may be null others may not be. Since row iterator skips the ones that are null, rowIndex is not the counter for absolute index. Also Iterator can not go back to get previous rows. What is the best row to obtain the absolute row index of the row that is two rows before the ID row?

Comment: maybe the first file has a space in the cell

Comment: @ScaryWombat I clicked on a few cells in the first row for both files, no space was found. I just don't understand why the row iterator skips rows that are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel spreadsheets can be sparse, both for rows and for columns.

In the underlying data, rows are sequentially listed, with row number implicitly incrementing by 1 for each row, however a row can specify its row number, thereby skipping a number of (blank) rows.

Example:

```
row
row
row num=5
row
```

This data defines rows 1, 2, 5, and 6.

The same concept applies to cells of a row.

So, if anything was ever done for a row, the row exists, even if you clear all values and formats. If nothing was ever done for a row, it *may* be skipped in the underlying data.

So, does a blank row actually exist or is it skipped? Depends. You should code logic to handle both ways. That way you don't care.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [cunningly titled "Iterating over Rows and Cells" section of the Apache POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) (whoever might have guessed?), you either should iterate over the rows explicitly with code like:

```
// Decide which rows to process
int rowStart = Math.min(15, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
int rowEnd = Math.max(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());

for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
   Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
   if (r == null) {
      // This whole row is empty
      // Handle it as needed
      continue;
   }

   int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
      }
   }
}
```

Otherwise, ask the [Row what row number it is](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getRowNum%28%29)! And do iterating like:

```
for (Sheet sheet : wb ) {
    for (Row row : sheet) {
       int rowIndex = row.getRowNum();
       // Handle cells here
    }
}
```